# How to add read more button in yajra data table

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

How to show less text on a table using button yajra datatables

Comment: Look at the documentation : https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/add-column

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a render function client-side, within the script that renders the datatable to adjust how the data is rendered.

If you just want to show the data that is coming through from the server, then your column probably looks like this :

```
{data: 'views', name: 'views', sortable:true, searchable: false},
```

If you need to do something to that data, however, then you need to add a render function to wrap that data within other HTML. Below is a simple example from one of my projects. In that, the price of the listing is coming through from the server, but I want to add a £ sign before it to make it more clear to the user :

```
{data: 'price', name: 'price',
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return '£' + data;
    },
    sortable: true,
    searchable : false
}
```

Within the render function, the actual data coming through from the server is available as "data", so I just add a pound sign before it and return that as the result of the function.

If you want to add a read more button - you've not specified whether that you want that to take the user to another page, or to just initially show part of the description and then show all of it when the user clicks on the button - then that's the way to do it.